# Different behaviour for getting environemnt variable after moving to nuget package

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a behaviour that I cannot explain in my application.

I have a common library which I;ve used across multiple projects. In this library I'm using System.Environment class to access environment variables, like so.

```
 string value = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MY_ENV_VARIABLE");
```

I've decided to create a nuget package for this shared library, and after moving my reference to the nuget, the `value` is not set anymore, as if the searched env_variable does not exist.

In an asp.net core project, I'm setting the environment variable

launch.json =>

```
 "environmentVariables": {
    "MY_ENV_VARIABLE": "my value"
  },
```

Why this behaviour ? switching back to direct referencing the project, everythign works.

Comment: Environment variables are *environment* variables, not something read from `launch.json`. Accessing them doesn't change no matter where the code is. Is the environment variable set on the machines you tried? Have you actually set it in Windows ? If you open a console and type `SET` do you see them?

Comment: `launch.json` is used by Visual Studio/Code to hold debugging settings and environment variables used during debugging the primary executable *only*. That's why it's called `launch.json`. It's not used in production at all. In production you need to set the environment variable in the OS. If you have problems during debugging ensure the environment variable is set in your ASP.NET Core project's launch.json. Even better, set them using your project's `Settings > Debug` page, to ensure you set them for the correct profile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I wrote the comments I realized I forgot to set the correct environment variable for console projects *at the OS level*. I had set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` but not `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT`. Things worked during debugging but once I tried to run the published executable - boom.

Guess I need to write this so I don't forget it again.

**Short Version**

`launch.json` is only used during debugging. Make sure you set the environment variables in the top-level project's `launch.json`. If you want to launch your application with eg development settings outside Visual Studio, you need to set `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` at the OS level. Same for any other environment variable.

**Explanation**

Environment variables are provided by the OS *environment*, they aren't read from launch.json. Accessing them doesn't change no matter where the code is. If you can't read the environment variable you want, it means it's not set.

Environment variables are usually set at the OS level (in all OSs). They can also be set temporarily in batch/shell files. Parent applications can also set the environment variables used by a child process when they launch it. That's what `launch.json` is used for.

Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code us it to store debugging profiles, settings and the environment variables they set when they start debugging the primary executable only. It's not used in production at all. If you have problems during debugging ensure the environment variable is set in your ASP.NET Core project's launch.json. Even better, set them using your project's `Settings > Debug` page, to ensure you set them for the correct profile.

**Production/Testing/Staging**

In production you need to set the environment variable in the OS.

If you use IIS  you can also set them in the `web.config` file used to configure hosting. This would allow you to deploy the same application twice on the same machine with different settings, eg for testing and staging. You could also use it for multi-tenant deployments, by using different basic settings for each site.

If you use containers you can also set environment variables at the container level. This allows you to use the same image with different settings and even deploy new settings when starting a container